# Want to zip up folder with 20K images to upload, how to breakup zips and then unzip?

Tags: ubuntu, zip, tar, upload

I have a folder with about 1 gig worth of images I have to upload to a server.

I want to zip/tar them up, preferably into multiple files that I can upload to my ubuntu server.

Then I want to unzip/untar them.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't compress a folder containing images unless they're stored in an uncompressed format (hope it's not the case); however use:

```
tar -c ~/directory/ | gzip | split -d -a 3 -b 100M - out_
```

to zip and split `~/directory/` in `out_000`, `out_001`, ... each one 100MB big (adjust the `-a` parameter to change the prefix length to your needs). And:

```
cat out_* | gunzip | tar -x
```

to restore the directory.

If you just want to split/un-split the directory simply remove the commands `gzip` and `gunzip` from the pipelines.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest raring them. Ubuntu has a few packages that can handle them and it seems to handle breaking up the archive the best.

Comment: Rar is not an open source format, has only proprietary tools to work with on Ubuntu, is not installed by default and thus would probably require administrative access. Even stupid `tar|split` is a better option.

Comment: @whitequark Just because its closed source does NOT mean that its bad. In some cases open source is a **worse** option.

Comment: @Lord.Quackstar Yes. But in this particular case it is worse: there are plenty of good open-source compressors (7-Zip at least), and support for Linux version of rar is actually pretty bad.

Comment: I am sorry did the op ask for open source? I didn't see that. Off your high horse sir.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use tar and 7zip on them. In some cases 7zip can provide better compression that rar and is also free software.